# 502 Error when connecting to WordPress admin using Laravel Valet

Tags: php, nginx, homebrew, macos-mojave

Currently experiencing issues with Laravel Valet where I am able to run some sites normally that have only a few SQL requests such as the front end of WordPress but if you navigate to /wp-admin I'm presented with 502 Bad Gateway.

Current Setup:

- MySQL 5.7
- PHP 7.3.6
- Nginx 1.17.1
- Composer 1.8.6
- Brew (Latest Version)
- Laravel Valet 2.3.3
- Mac OS 10.14.5 (Clean install from the ground up)

I have followed the Laravel Valet installation tutorial by each step exactly. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet#installation

The error in the file nginx-error.log is as follows:

> *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: demo.test, request: "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/admin/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "demo.test", referrer: "https://demo.test/"

I've tried this on another users computer and they also fall foul of the same issue.

Fixes I've tried:

- Tried using `valet install` to fix permissions & config
- Restarting php & nginx `sudo brew services restart nginx && sudo brew services restart php`
- Changing the Nginx buffer sizes
- Simple computer reboot
- Tried to build PHP from source but no luck on downloading the file (via brew)
- `brew uninstall php; brew install php --build-from-source; valet install`
- Brew's cleanup & doctor

It would be very helpful if anyone could shine some light on this as looking around people seem to have the same problem and there is no clear fix.

- https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/717
- https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/269
- https://medium.com/@stefanledin/502-bad-gateway-when-starting-laravel-valet-a-solution-a2ef3c5c2f8e